# CSS text align center vertically do not center

Tags: html, css

**Important:**

My post is (normally) not duplicate. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers?rq=1) post on Stack Overflow (and there are maybe all duplicates). I try the most common answer of this posts but it do not works. I also tried other ways but I can not achieve my goal.

So, I have a big div with a text:

```css
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#dimScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

h1 {
    font-size:350%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dimScreen" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center; display:inline-block;">
    <h1 >Big text</h1> 
</div>
```

My problem is that I can not figure how can I put the text in the center (vertically+horizontally) of my gray div. As you can see, the text appear in the center (horizontally) of the div but not in the center vertically. I set the center (vertically+horizontally) on the body's part.

In my example, I try to align text vertically with the most common response of all this posts but it do not works. I already tried other ways, that we can find in the questions linked, but they do not work: we always have the same result.

I think I have this problem because I display my (gray) div on all the page. I tried on a normal div and the code works: my text is center vertically.

Short question:

*How can I center vertically my text on the gray div?*

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Sphynx.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5m0ux077/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Flexbox` you can set text vertically center in div

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#dimScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size:350%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dimScreen">
    <h1 >Big text</h1> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the `table-layout` to include older browser .

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: table
}

#dimScreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 350%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dimScreen" style="">
  <h1>Big text</h1>
</div>
```

**Note** : `vertical-align:center;` is not a valid value. You probably wanted  `middle`.